On Git Bash -> double click on a file path selects the whole path on windows but on mac this doesn't seem to happen
On windows when I double click on a file :

Whereas on Mac, when I double click on a file :

This double click and select whole path feature comes very handy and saves a lot of time when we've to deal with lot of files.
Is there any way we can achieve this on mac. or any other handy way we can do this on mac

Double click behavior is a function of the terminal, not the shell; this is not specific to Git or bash! Obviously Windows does have a  terminal that's different from the terminal of macOS. So these kind of differences are to be expected. Also you can install other terminals, if you so desire.
